# function that should Generate matrix with sums of rows/columns defined as input lists

Tags: python, matrix, random

I've a task to make fuction that generates matrix from non negative integers in range (0-8)

- Input of the function are 2 lists :

  - sumForEveryCol
  - sumForEveryRow
- Each list contains sum of the values for every rows/columns
- Example: sumForEveryRow should contain sums for every row by it's index ( sumForEveryRow[0] = sum of the first row ... etc.)
- sumForEveryColumn[0] = sum of the first column .. sumForEveryColumn[1] - second column .. etc.)
- Sum of every row or column is constant value of 40
- Value of any cell should be in range 0, 8

I've strange ideas (code below) but there is no chance to work at all.. because of the algorithm... What is the algorithm in general to generate such matrix and what is the best way to implement it in python

Example:

```
sumsForEveryRow = [4,20,8,8] = constant 40
sumsForEveryCol = [8,8,8,8,8] = constant 40

gen_matrix(sumForEveryRow, sumForEveryCol) should produce random matrix like:

[ 0 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 2 ],  - sum of row 1 should be 4
[ 1 , 2 , 8 , 5 , 4 ],  - sum of row 2 should be 20
[ 3 , 2 , 0 , 3 , 0 ],  - sum of row 3 should be 8
[ 4 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 2 ],  - sum of row 4 should be 8
sum for every column should be
  8   8   8   8   8



import random
import numpy

sumsForEveryCol = [8,8,8,8,8]
sumsForEveryRow = [4,20,8,8]
def gen_matrix(sumForEveryCol, sumForEveryRow):
    sum = 40
    max_value_cell = 8
    num_of_rows = len(sumsForEveryRow)
    num_of_cols = len(sumsForEveryCol)
    matrix = numpy.zeros((num_of_rows, num_of_cols), dtype=numpy.int)

    for i in range(0, num_of_rows - 1):
        cur_row_sum = sumsForEveryRow[i]
        for j in range(0, num_of_cols - 1):
            if max_value_cell >= cur_row_sum:
                if cur_row_sum == 0:
                    matrix[i][j] = 0
                else:
                    # Dont generate 0 values ????
                    rand_digit = random.randint(1, cur_row_sum)
                    cur_row_sum = cur_row_sum - rand_digit
                    matrix[i][j] = rand_digit
            else:
                rand_digit = random.randint(0, max_value_cell)
                matrix[i][j] = rand_digit
                cur_row_sum = cur_row_sum - rand_digit


    return matrix
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "random"? If you say that "non-random" is a red herring, so that every non-random function is just a special case of a random function ([Delta measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#As_a_measure)), that's trivial. If by "random" you mean that the distribution should be uniform on the set of all possible solutions, then it could be somewhat more complicated to implement. Specify what kind of "randomness" you have in mind.

Comment: I don't need set of all possible solutions at all. I need one answer that satisfy the conditions of the task...

Comment: As already said above: if you need one answer, and don't care about the solution, then implement the deterministic algorithm that finds the first solution. But then you should delete the "random" from the name of `gen_random_matrix`. Otherwise you would have to specify what you mean by "random".

Comment: "What is the algorithm" -- why the word "the"? There are numerous approaches e.g. backtracking. I'm lazy so my personal preference would be to write a quick evolutionary algorithm (this reminds me a bit of magic squares and I have had good success evolving magic squares).

Comment: This can be thought of as a type of [transportation problem](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Operations_Research/Transportation_and_Assignment_Problem) with a dummy objective function. The columns can be thought of as sources and the rows can be thought of as sinks. The target column numbers can be thought of as supplies and the row target numbers as demands. A number, `x`, in position `(i,j)` corresponds to `x` units flowing from source `i` to sink `j`. The restrictions on the `x` can be viewed as capacities on the edges. The simplex algorithm could solve it, though probably overkill.